# C# textbox stop flickering

Tags: c#, textbox

I have a multiline textbox where I display app log. If the length is > than 1k characters, I substr the log. The problem is that it's flickering. I use timer control to update textbox with condition if data differs.

Any way around this? or is there a better way to show log? Thanks!

```
// this is inside timer
if(txt_log.Text != MY_LOG_VAR){
   txt_log.Text = MY_LOG_VAR;
}

// function to update log
public void Log(string data){

  MY_LOG_VAR = data + "\r\n" + MY_LOG_VAR;

  if(MY_LOG_VAR.Length > 1000){
     substr...
  }
}
```

The Log function could be called even 20 times a second, the timer interval is set to 100 seconds;

it doesn't flicker much, but if a lot of data is submitted to the log it does, I need a solution that would allow the textbox to be even full screen and not flicker..  Thanks!

Comment: Please show the code where you update the textbox

Comment: are you setting the text property each time ?

Comment: are you doing the > 1000 check every time the user types something? if so exactly what event are you handling to do it? I suspect its the wrong one...and a timer in this scenario doesn't sound right.

Comment: Updated the code. It's just used to debug application, its a network app so it shows what's its doing.

Comment: You can try calling `SuspendLayout` before updating and `ResumeLayout` after to see if that stops the flickering.. however I doubt it will help much when you're updating the textbox ever 100ms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to use [TextBox.AppendText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.appendtext.aspx) instead of replacing the entire content of your textbox.

```
// function to update log 
public void Log(string data)
{ 
  textBox1.AppendText(data + "\r\n");
  MY_LOG_VAR = data + "\r\n" + MY_LOG_VAR; 

}
```

This is not the same as putting the new text in front of the previous one, but I think that should stop the flicker.
I have done some test with a RichTextBox and there is no flicker at all 
(exactly as Hans Passant said in its answer)...

For example, scrolling without flickering

```
 richTextBox1.AppendText(data +"\n");
 richTextBox1.SelectionStart = richTextBox1.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(richTextBox1.Lines.Count()-1);
 richTextBox1.ScrollToCaret();
```

Answer (score 2):

There isn't anything you can do about the way TextBox paints.  It commits a few sins, like painting without WM_PAINT, that mattered a great deal back in 1985 when it had to run on severely constrained hardware.  1K chars is rather at the low end, 64K is a nice round number that will reduce the flicker.  And be sure to use AppendText in between.

Beyond that, do consider RichTextBox instead.  It double-buffers and has a better way to make the text read-only.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried surrounding your update with calls to BeginUpdate/EndUpdate on the textbox?

Comment: That doesn't exist.